# Grub broken after warm boot Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows

I have a Thinkpad with a 2nd SSD with Ubuntu on it. Grub works fine on a cold boot. It works fine after a warm Ubuntu boot. But when warm booting from windows I get dumped to a grub> prompt. If I do an ls here, it shows all my (hd0) devices, but is missing the (hd1) devices where ubuntu is. If I cold boot and go to the grub prompt, then I can see the (hd1) devices. So something is going on whereby warm booting windows stops grub accessing (hd1). When the warm boot fails, I have to do a cold boot to fix it. In the bios I've got everything to do with secure boot turned off, and I can't see anything in there that would affect this.

Comment: Are both UEFI (or both old BIOS) installs? What brand/model system? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: It's a Thinkpad E15 Gen2 (A very new model). The boot info is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MK8YZcBpW3/

Comment: Your Ubuntu entry is in the nvme0n1 with the Windows entry. And your fstab also refers to that ESP, not the ESP on the nvme1n1 drive. Both ESP have a grub configfile referring to your install. You may be able to just totally reinstall grub from within your install, but have to change /etc/fstab to use UUID of ESP on Ubuntu drive and reboot, so it is the one a reinstall will use. See efibootmgr example with NVMe drive in VI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: Hmm, maybe. But if it can't even see the NVMe drive after warm booting windows, maybe this would be worse because it still can't boot from it. Is there any reason to believe that grub would be able to work as you suggest, while it can't even see the drive with "ls"?

Comment: You need to see NVMe as a device in /dev/nvmeXXXX.  Is the warm boot of Windows turning a fast start or hibernation setting back on?

Comment: I have fast Start turned off. And since I'm initiating reboot I can't think it would be hibernate. One can't ls /dev in grub so how do I look at that?